# hamburger menu wont expand when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, responsive

I tried to make a hamburger menu.

Here is my HTML :

```
<nav>
    <h3>Life Below Water</h3>
    <ul class="ul">
        <li><a href="" class="nav">Donate</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://sdgs.un.org/goals" class="nav">Visit SDG.UN</a></li>
    </ul>
        
    <a href="#" class="toggle" id="menuicon"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
</nav>
```

Here is my JS :

```
const toggle = document.getElementByClassName('menuicon')[0]
const navBar = document.getElementByClassName('ul')[0]


menuicon.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    navBar.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

It doesn't expand the menu when I click the hamburger icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementByClassName` should be `getElementsByClassName`:

```js
const toggle = document.getElementsByClassName('menuicon')[0]
const navBar = document.getElementsByClassName('ul')[0]


menuicon.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    navBar.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
.ul{
  display:none;
}

.active{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-YWzhKL2whUzgiheMoBFwW8CKV4qpHQAEuvilg9FAn5VJUDwKZZxkJNuGM4XkWuk94WCrrwslk8yWNGmY1EduTA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<nav>
    <h3>Life Below Water</h3>
    <ul class="ul">
        <li><a href="" class="nav">Donate</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://sdgs.un.org/goals" class="nav">Visit SDG.UN</a></li>
    </ul>
        
    <a href="#" class="toggle" id="menuicon"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
</nav>
```